# MSBuild can't find package for .NET Standard project in solution with other .NET Framework projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, .net-standard

I have a Visual Studio Solution with:

- 2 .NET Standard 2.0 projects (`.csproj`)

  - `proj A` (class library): proj refs -> `proj B`, no Nuget packages
  - `proj B` (class library): no proj refs, no Nuget packages
- 2 .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects (`.csproj`)

  - `proj C` (class library): proj refs -> `proj B`, several Nuget packages
  - `proj D` (test project): proj refs -> `proj C`, `proj B` & `proj A`, several Nuget packages

This solution built fine on my local machine running VS Community 2017 15.7.3
This solution also builds fine on my build machine which is using `MSBuild` from the same VS of the same version.

**Problem**

The problem occurs when I add a Nuget package (in this case `Newtonsoft`) to `proj A`. The solution builds fine on my local machine but *doesn't* work when using `MSBuild`. Also, if I load the solution on my build machine using the VS installed there, it builds fine.

The error getting raised is:

`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I think I've narrowed down the issue to an issue where `.NET Standard` & `.NET Framework` projects don't play well together with Nuget when they're in the same `.sln` because if I completely remove `proj C` & `proj D` the build succeeds on my build machine. I can also confirm that the `Newtonsoft` package is in my `C:/User/.nuget/packages` folder, but is not in the `./packages` folder of the solution directory (which I'm pretty sure if supposed to happen since it's a `.NET Standard` project?).

**CI `.yml` File**

```
nuget.exe restore $SOLUTION_FILE
MSBuild.exe '/p:Configuration=release' $SOLUTION_FILE
```

**Notes**

I've done a lot of reading trying to find issues similar to this, but the closest I get is issues that look a lot like [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481). This issue is similar but is using the `.NET Standard` project itself as a Nuget package where as I'm trying to get Nuget packages into the `.NET Standard` project itself. Maybe I need to extract all of my `.NET Standard` projects into a Nuget package instead of using them in the same solution?

Comment: Do your .NETframework projects contain packages.config file?

Comment: @AnkitMishra yes they do.

Comment: Where is the error CS0246 comes from, `proj A` or `proj D` ? You can build the project one by one, not the solution. If the error comes from the `proj D`, you should add the package `Newtonsoft` to the `proj D`. If the error comes from the `proj A`, please try to restore the nuget package with command line: `msbuild /t:restore "YourSolutionFile.sln"

Comment: Using `msbuild /t:restore "YourSolutionFile.sln"` was the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Leo Lieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-liu-msft) pointed out, using `msbuild /t:restore "YourSolutionFile.sln"` was the trick, although I had to do it as well as running `nuget.exe restore "YourSolutionFile.sln"` which I find peculiar...

Comment: this should be the standard and source for the answer - https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481